# How do you rotate your alpha brush in sculpting mode?

Tags: sculpting

I have my standard brush loaded with a texture (alpha image), and I'm wondering if it's possible to rotate the alpha on the fly or otherwise, preferably with drag dot as the stroke.

Comment: Do you mean the Stencil image, in the 3D view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you're referring to the stencil image in the 3D view, Then you can achieve that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Right click.
Additionally, you can move the stencil image using Right click, you can scale it using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right click.

[image]